# MKMapView - Choppy Zoom Animation

Tags: ios, mkmapview

I am using an animation technique to improve upon the zooming of user location.  It essentially zooms out to the world view and then down to the local view.  The zoom process itself works just fine but the map rendering doesn't look very good.  Essentially during the zoom animation you see the grid cut in an out as the map itself renders.  This is actually true of the "standard" map as well as the "Sat" or "Hybrid" maps.

I am not sure if this is a cache issue or just the rendering engine in conjunction with the phone's hardware not being fast enough?  This occurs on the sim as well as on the device (an iPhone 5 in this case running ios 8.x). Any way to improve visual performance here?

```
MKCoordinateRegion worldRegion = MKCoordinateRegionForMapRect(MKMapRectWorld);
            MKCoordinateRegion viewRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(zoomLocation, .5*METERS_PER_MILE, .5*METERS_PER_MILE);

            [MKMapView animateWithDuration:3.0 animations:^{
                [self.mapView setRegion:worldRegion animated:YES];
            } completion:^(BOOL finished){
                [MKMapView animateWithDuration:3.0 animations:^{
                    [self.mapView setRegion:viewRegion animated:YES];
                }completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                    NSLog(@"Final complete");
                }];
            }];
```

Comment: This is a limitation of MakKit  it has to download all the map tiles as it animates. You can try to slow down your animation to reduce the amount of empty grid space you see. Also, you seem to be doing a double animation, the setRegion:animaged: method will animate the map so there is not need for the animateWithDuration block.  Looks like you are using it to trigger the next animation but that's not really the best way to do it. You may want to use some of the other mapView delegates like `regionDidChangeAnimated` to track the animation process.

Comment: Slowing it down more takes too long from a user experience perspective and doesn't actually help much if at all.  Regarding the "double animation", this is necessary as the default animation you are speaking of is far too fast.  The reason I went this way was to slow down the default and give it a nicer effect.

Comment: btw you animate WHILE setRegions animates itself

Comment: @jaro, please explain further.

Comment: sue [self.mapView setRegion:viewRegion animated:NO];   instead of [self.mapView setRegion:viewRegion animated:YES];

Comment: I understand, but that doesn't work.  The map doesn't animate, it simply warps directly to the spot.  As a result the effect is not achieved.  This tells me what the animation block does not work with the setRegion to animate the values between one point and another.